# mx record mail server coming back as something else so cert isn't correct

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I'm adding a certificate to my mail server and everything works fine, except I am getting an error when using [www.checktls.com](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver) to make sure everything is running correctly.

This is the error from checktls:

```
Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY (randomlettersandstuff.domain.com != mail.domain.com | DNS:mail.domain.com)
```

This is my MX record:

```
TYPE  NAME        MAIL SERVER      TTL  PRIORITY
MX    domain.com  mail.domain.com  300  0
```

When I do an nslookup of `domain.com` I get this:

```
domain.com   MX preference = 0, mail exchanger = randomlettersandstuff.domain.com
```

My mail server works fine, I can send and recieve emails perfectly and in thunderbird I get no cert errors (popups saying that I need to add an exception).

Why does everything (except thunderbird) think my mail server is `randomlettersandstuff.domain.com` and not `mail.domain.com`?

Comment: What is the subject and alternative names (if any) in your certificate?

Comment: @Vadim How would i check that? The certificate is automatically generated for me, for my domain.

Comment: I got returned this when trying to get the subject of my cert: `subject= /CN=mail.domain.com`. I don't think there are any alternative names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I had a CNAME for `mail.domain.com` and it was being proxied by Cloudflare. When I switched it to DNS only, nslookup returned the correct mail exchanger: `mail.domain.com` instead of `randomletters.domain.com`.